# PyPi Server Response 500

Tags: python, setup.py, pypi

I'm trying to regsiter my package on PyPi, with the following command:

```
pyton setup.py register
```

But it results in the following error:

```
Server response (500): <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
```

I even deleted the ~/.pypirc file and tried again issuing the command but that too results in the same error. My setup.py script is as follows:

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools import find_packages
setup(
        name="xxxxx",
        version="0.0.1",
        author="someone",
        author_email="someone@gmail.com",
        url="https://github.com/someone",
        packages=['folder_name',],
        license="MIT License",
        description = " Sample Description",
        long_description = open("README").read(),
        install_requires = ["python-mwapi"],
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Importing setup from distutils solved the issue.

Replacing the first two lines with this made it work:

```
from distutils.core import setup
```

And once you have registered your package name using `distutils.core`, you can again go back and use `setuptools` in your setup.py file. From then on everything seems to work fine.

Answer (score 4):

Check your internet connection, and whether a firewall on the network or on the machine you are working on might be restricting your access.

Next step in troubleshooting is to specify the Pypi server:

```
python setup.py register -r http://pypi.python.org/pypi
```

then if still failing mysteriously try to run a local Pypi server ([pypiserver](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiserver)) and run the command above while specifying that server.

Answer (score 4):

Adding this to my ~/pypirc worked for me as explained in [Uploading to PyPI](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing.html#uploading-your-project-to-pypi).

```
[distutils]
index-servers=pypi

[pypi]
repository = https://pypi.python.org/pypi

[pypi]
username:your_username
password:your_password
```